# QWebEngineView don't playing youtube stream

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

```
webview = QWebEngineView()
webview.load(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzBGEqkwCoY"))
```

When I put link on live stream show message:

```
Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available
```

How i can fix this or where else i can play youtube stream, which module?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 8.1, 64x

Comment: You need the proprietary codecs that do not come with the pyqtwebengine provided by pyqt so you will have to compile it manually